In ggplot2, how do I move my title to the left (NOT left aligned--on the lefthand side)?
I have a plot, and I want the title to be on the lefthand side (not left aligned). In other words, I want it to the left of "Percent" with some space. Everything I have read just shows how to make it left aligned. Any help would be appreciated!
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data
data <- data.frame(
  satisfaction = c("Unhappy", "Neutral", "Happy"),
  percent = c(20, 40, 30)
)

# Define colors for each level
colors <- c("Unhappy" = "red", "Neutral" = "gray", "Happy" = "green")

# Plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = satisfaction, y = percent, fill = satisfaction)) +
  geom_col() +
  guides(fill = "none") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  ggtitle("Your Title")  # I want this on the left of percent but going horizontal


@zephryl, thanks for looking into this! I just removed the legend. But, basically I want the title to be like the legend was but on the left. Just how the legend was read left to right, that's how I want the title to be

Are you looking for + theme(plot.title.position = "plot")?

@stefan, no that's just left aligning the title. I want it to the left of the plot entirely

Possible option:
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data
data <- data.frame(
  satisfaction = c("Unhappy", "Neutral", "Happy"),
  percent = c(20, 40, 30)
)

# Define colors for each level
colors <- c("Unhappy" = "red", "Neutral" = "gray", "Happy" = "green")

# Plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = satisfaction, y = percent, fill = satisfaction)) +
  geom_col() +
  guides(fill = "none") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, NA), clip = "off") +
  annotate("text", x = -0.08, y = 20, label = "Your Title") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,4), "lines"))


Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0

One option would be to use patchwork to add your plot title as a separate grob:
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = satisfaction, y = percent, fill = satisfaction)) +
  geom_col() +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors)

library(patchwork)

list(
  grid::textGrob("My Ttitle"),
  p
) |> 
  wrap_plots() +
  plot_layout(width = c(.1, .9))


